# How to access HTMLDocument from web-sys?

Tags: rust, webassembly

Using the [web-sys crate](https://crates.io/crates/web-sys/0.3.6), I want to access the [cookie method](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.HtmlDocument.html?search=#method.cookie) from the `HTMLDocument`.

I want to do something like this. Indeed this does not work.

```
let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
let document = window.document().unwrap();
let cookie = document.cookie().unwrap();
//no method named `cookie` found for type `web_sys::features::gen_Document::Document` in the current scope
```

I would need to access the `HTMLDocument` struct not the `Document` struct.

Cargo.toml with features enabled.

```
~snip~
[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3.4"
features = [
  "WebSocket",
  'Window',
  'Document',
  'HtmlDocument',
]
```

According to the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument), it should be accessible under `Window`, like `Document`.

It does not seem to be available with something like:

```
let html_document = window.html_document().unwrap();
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument), `HTMLDocument` should extend `Document`.

I know there is no inheritance in Rust but I cannot convert it from `Document` as such:

```
let html_document = web_sys::HtmlDocument::from(document);
```

It is the same with the `into` function.

Is it possible to access `HTMLDocument` in such a way?

Is there another way to access the cookie using web-sys?

Is it something work-in-progress that is not working right now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a *dynamic cast*, that is done with [`wasm_bindgen::JsCast::dyn_into()`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html#method.dyn_into):

```
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
let document = window.document().unwrap();
let html_document = document.dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlDocument>().unwrap();
let cookie = html_document.cookie().unwrap();
```

There is also the variant [`wasm_bindgen::JsCast::dyn_ref()`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html#method.dyn_ref) that does not consume the original object.